# How can I relate a row with several other rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In my situation, I have a table of postcodes. I want each row to have a list of surrounding postcodes.

With the app I'm developing, I want to be able to search by a postcode/suburb and include postcodes that are nearby. Say within 2 miles. I know how to identify postcodes surrounding suburbs, but don't know how to associate these so that I could retrieve the surrounding suburbs for a postcode in my model.

For example in the below, postcode `0001` might be surrounded by `0003`, and `0004`

```
id | postcodes         
1  | 0001          
2  | 0002
3  | 0003
4  | 0004
```

I'm very unsure about how to build this model. Would I need a separate table that associates postcodes with their neighbors? Could this be done within the one table?

If it assists, I'm running PostgreSQL with Python SQLAlchemy ORM.

Thanks for any help. Happy to answer any questions that will assist.

Comment: Where is the information on what the adjoining postcodes are?  For instance, do you have the latitude and longitude of them?

Comment: I'm using http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPostalCodes to pull the nearby suburbs/postcodes. I already have a table of postcodes and will just be iterating through them to add the nearby suburbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky thing as this is essentially 'graph' data and this can be hard to work with. A few questions:

Are those "surrounding" codes calculable based on the data in the table? Or is a magic knowledge that needs to be set in the table?

Do you have this when adding a row or is this being updated later?

Does this change (rearly?, often? never?) or is this a constant table?

Two things you can do is:
1) create a new table with this data
2) create a new column holding an array with those surrounding codes. This can even be efficiently indexed and searched through in Postgress.

The con of new table is that it is a new table. The pro is that you can define a column as foreign key and if you delete you can take advantage of this.

The pro of a column with an array is you do not need a new table but the con is you cannot define it as a foreign key so if any codes get deleted you will be responsible for writing some kind of procedure to clean those codes from the arrays.

This would look like this:

```
id | postcodes | adjecent
1  | 0001      | {0003, 0004, ...}
2  | 0002      | {...}
3  | 0003      | {0001, ...}
4  | 0004      | {0001, ...}
```

The new table could be a simple pivot table:

```
id | adjecent
1  | 3
1  | 4
3  | 1
4  | 1
```

or a more complicated array table:

```
id | adjecent
1  | {3, 4}
3  | {1}
4  | {1}
```

Just remember that if you use an array you are using that foreign key info.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. I did consider several of the points you've made. It was my hope to avoid a new table as that would effectively reuse data as you said, but if that ends up being the only or best way, so it is.

The surrounding suburbs are not calculated by myself. If you'll see my comment under the original post, I'm using an API that identifies the nearby suburbs.

In theory, these nearby suburbs would never change. They should be static.

Comment: If the data is static the most performant way is to just pre-calculate it. If you never filter or order on the surrounding codes I would go with a new column holding an array. And even if you filter a GIST or GIN (sorry, I do not remember which one of those two) should give you a lot of milage.
To return a result you can always unnest the array and get a "normal" result.

Comment: While perhaps not the cleanest, I think a separate table might be best given your input.

Comment: It really depends on what you are going for. The cleanest solution is not always the most performant. I do not know how big will this data get but if gets really big there can be a large performance difference if you go with a table or a column. Consider this: if you do a new table you need to go to disc twice to build a row. Once to get the code and once to get the adjacent ids. With a column you go to disc once. But if you need this adjacency data in only a small fraction of queries a column might be worse as each query will read this data from the disc since it is part of the row.